# Emms play at certain time

Tags: emms

I wish to play certain music files, but from certain time. I find the seek forward/backward functions not the ones I need since they require me to fast forward/backward until I arrive at certain time.

What's the correct way of navigating through the music file to certain time from where I wish to play it?

Comment: Is it possible to visualize the time as it plays in the buffer bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`M-x emms-seek-to` with the argument `n`  jumps to `n`-th second of the track (for n=601 you get 10:01).

`M-x emms-seek` is also helpful.
From emms.el:

defun emms-seek (seconds): "Seek the current player SECONDS seconds. This can be a floating point number for sub-second fractions. It can also be negative to seek backwards."